# Sharepoint 2016 Sites Fail to Open

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016

I have deployed SharePoint 2016 and the Sites Collection site fails to load. Is there anything I might have overlooked in the setup? I am able to interact with the Central Administration, but not the Sites.

[image: screenshot]

The address is:

> `http://MyServer/my/_layouts/15/MySite.aspx?MySiteRedirect=AllSites`

Comment: have you setup user profile? what are the farm configurations?

Comment: I had setup the farm using one particular account, which I am still signed into. Every ever so often, when I try to browse to sites, it asks me to login and I use the credentials and it fails

Comment: are you trying to access the MySite or team site? did you disable the loopbackcheck on the server?

Comment: I am trying to access the Sites link from the Central Administrator Dashboard. Based on the URL i figure that would be MySite and yes, I have disable loopbackcheck via Powershell

Comment: on your web app, what type of Site collection you have at roots? Mysite site host or team site? try to create the root level site collection as Team site and test it